# Using BinaryWriter on an Object

Tags: c#, database, binarywriter

My application is a small C# database, and I'm using `BinaryWriter` to save the database to a file which is working fine with the basic types such as bool, uint32 etc.
Although I've got a variable that is of type `Object` (allowing the user to store any data type), however as my application doesn't (nor needs to) know the real type of this variable, I'm unsure how to write it using `BinaryWriter`.
Is there a way I could perhaps grab the memory of the variable and save that? Would that be reliable?

**Edit:**

The answer provided by ba_friend has two functions for de/serialising an Object to a byte array, which can be written along with its length using a BinaryWriter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use serialization for that, especially the `BinaryFormatter` to get a `byte[]`.
**Note**: The types you are serializing must be marked as **Serializable** with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

```
public static byte[] SerializeToBytes<T>(T item)
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

---

```
public static object DeserializeFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've worked out how to use that when serialising, although I can't see how to deserialise using this technique - I've updated the question text appropriately.

Comment: Hahaha! :) Oh my, I'm trying to work it out from numerous examples on the net and so far my function is 8 lines long compared to your elegant 3. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: This works but it's the slowest way to serialize anything in .net by far.

Comment: Microsoft recommends against using BinaryFormatter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide