# Binary writing (var/object)

Tags: c#, casting, binary, var

In my program, I will get a `var` object at run time  and I would like to write it to a binary file, but I couldn't write `var` variable by using `BinaryWriter`. It gives a compile error that `cannot convert from 'object' to 'bool'`. How to solve it?

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)
var obj = Convert.ChangeType(property.GetValue(objectToWrite, null), property.PropertyType);
writer.Write(obj); //Compile error
```

Comment: This may be one solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759604/using-binarywriter-on-an-object

Comment: btw, the `Convert.ChangeType` here is redundant; the result from `GetValue` **must by necessity** already be of that type

Comment: @MarcGravell. You are correct again. I just noticed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` in this case will resolve to `object`, since that is what `GetValue` returns. There is no overload of `BinaryWriter.Write` that accepts `object`. What you want next depends on a few things:

- if your intent is to write a very simply value (a single `bool`, `int`, etc - something supported by `BinaryWriter`) to a file, then you will have to switch on the type of that simple value; a cheeky way to do that is to use `dynamic`, which will figure that out at runtime:

  ```
  writer.Write((dynamic)obj); // not great, but should work
  ```
- if your intent is to write a complex piece of data (a `class` / `struct` etc) then you shouldn't be using `BinaryWriter` - you should be using a *serializer*. Perhaps `BinaryFormatter` (although that has some serious kinks which makes me reluctant to recommend it) or protobuf-net, or similar

Comment: @Rambo out of curiosity... what is the actual data type here?

Comment: I am reading from a database. Database tables may contain int, float, string variables. I have to decide it dynamically and write it to a binary file

Comment: Why you are saying so? Actually I will write all the properties in the class instance in a loop or else do you recommend to write all the properties once?

Comment: Actually my requirement is, writing all the memeber variable values to a binary file

Comment: @Rambo I *strongly* suggest you look into pre-rolled serialization libraries; doing this by hand is not for the faint hearted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30438/discussion-between-rambo-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 0):

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create);
var obj = Convert.ChangeType(property.GetValue(objectToWrite, null), property.PropertyType);
writer.Write(obj);
```

Try to use `obj` instead of `var`.